# VBA : Disabling Listbox while macro is running

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, ms-office

### Problem

I have a macro (I'll call it `launch_macro`) which is launched by double-clicking in an Userform ListBox (`ListBox1_DblClick`).

My problem is that if the user double-click again while the macro is still running, the macro will be launched again as soon as the first execution is finished, regardless of the fact that I'm disabling ListBox while the macro is running.

### Code and tests

```
Private sub ListBox1_DblClick(Byval Cancel as MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

   (....Logging...)

    If Not Cancel Then
        Me.ListBox1.Enabled = False
        (...DisplayStatusBar / ScreenUpdating / ListBox1.BackColor...)
        launch_macro
        (...DisplayStatusBar / ScreenUpdating / ListBox1.BackColor...)
        Me.ListBox1.Enabled = True

    End If

End sub
```

It seems like Excel records/queues the **ListBox1_DblClick** events (for future execution) while the associated **ListBox is disabled**. Why that ? How can I prevent this ?

I also tried with no success :

- **Locked** : `Me.ListBox1.Locked = True`
- **Doevents** : Adding `DoEvents` after `Me.ListBox1.Enabled = False`
- **EnableEvents** :`Application.EnableEvents = False`
- **macroLaunched variable** :Using a variable to check if the macro is already launched (`macroLaunched = True` at the beginning of the `ListBox1_DblClick` event and `macroLaunched = False` at the end). This doesn't work since the second execution is launched **after** the end of the first event (thus the variable is set back to`False`). (And setting the variable back to False outside the scope of the Dbl_Click event is not acceptable since the user need to be able to launch the macro immediately again (but just not while the first execution is still running)).
- **Adding delay** (for test purpose only) :  I added a 10s delay (Application.Wait) right back after the launch_macro. I then double-clicked twice within 1s. The second execution still launched. I checked by logging : the 2nd ListBox1.Dbl_Click event is 'recorded' by Excel 12s after the first event.

**Note** : I'm using Office Standard 2013

### Current 'solution'

This trick is adapted (to reduce delay) from A.S.H answer :

```
Private sub ListBox1_DblClick(Byval Cancel as MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   Static nextTime As Single

   If Timer < nextTime then
        Log_macro "Event canceled because Timer < nextTime : " & Timer
        Exit Sub
   End if

   (....Logging...)

    If Not Cancel Then
        (...DisplayStatusBar / ScreenUpdating / ListBox1.BackColor...)
        launch_macro
        (...DisplayStatusBar / ScreenUpdating / ListBox1.BackColor...)

    End If

    nextTime = Timer + 0.5
    Log_macro "nextTime = " & nextTime

End sub
```

It 'does the trick' but but I still don't like that ListBox1 is still enabled and Excel is still queueing events, thus I need to estimate how many time the user might Dbl_Click (depending on how long the macro takes) to estimate how much a delay I need (currently 0.5s to be able to handle (and log) at least 10 canceled events). Also, it seems like Excel doesn't really like (in regards to performance) queuing events while the macro is running.

Comment: @YowE3K. Just tested `EnableEvents` ; that doesn't work either. :-(

Comment: Yeah - I realised that this was on an actual form, so decided that probably **wasn't** going to be the right answer, so deleted the comment.

Comment: I just tried this and double-clicking again in the ListBox while the macro is running **didn't** fire off the code again unless I included a `DoEvents` (because user activity is locked out) and, with the `DoEvents` in the code, the second execution ran concurrently with the first execution - i.e. it didn't wait for the first execution to finish.

Comment: Before launch_macro, check if macroLaunched is true. If it is, don't launch the macro. if not, set it to true before launch_macro. Set macroLaunched outside of the doubleClick event, when it's acceptable to launch the macro again.

Comment: @RichHolton. I forgot to write that I already tested the `macroLaunched = True` variable approach. It doesn't work since the second execution is launched **after** the variable is set back to `False`.

And setting the variable back to `False` **outside** the scope of the Dbl_Click event is not acceptable since the user need to be able to launch the macro immediately again (but just not while the first execution is still running).

Comment: The `Me.ListBox1.Enabled = False` (with or without a `DoEvents`) also works for me, i.e. the double clicks are ignored while it is disabled.  Is it possible that the second double-click is occurring during the "logging", i.e. before you disable the list box?

Comment: I checked again. There is not `DoEvents`anywhere in the macro. Logging is much to quick to be the problem and I still have the problem when putting `Me.ListBox1.Enabled = False`at the very beginning. I don't get why I'm the only one having the problem...

Comment: @YowE3K the pattern described by OP is consistently reproducible for me. I'm currently on Excel 2007.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks. I'm using Office Standard 2013

Comment: I'm on Office Pro 2010.

Comment: @Tibo I can suggest you a workaround such that after the macro is run, at least 3 seconds should pass before launching it again. This way if there are pending double-clicks in the event queue, they are flushed out with no effect. Is that a viable solution for you?

Comment: @A.S.H Still doesn't work for me. I added a 10s delay (Application.Wait) right back after the launch_macro. I then double-clicked twice within 1s. The second execution still launched. I checked by logging : the 2nd `ListBox1.Dbl_Click` event is 'recorded' by Excel 12s after the first event. :-(

Comment: @Tibo I have a solution to achieve that, I asked you if it solves your issue to post it as an answer

Comment: @A.S.H Your previous suggestion (delay) doesn't work for me (see my previous comment)... I am missing something ?

Comment: @Tibo maybe I didn't make my idea clear enough. Please try the method in my answer below.

Comment: tibo, Just curious--when you tried the flag approach, did you use a local variable? If so, try again with one declared at the module level.

Comment: @RichHolton. Module (Private) variable ; still don't work since when the 2nd `Dbl_Click `event is called, the variable has already been set back to `True` at the end of the first Event. (PS See my comment to A.S.H answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I will post my suggestion, I hope you try it because may be it was misunderstood. The idea is that once the macro is finished, we set a delay of n seconds (say 2 seconds) before handling again the double-click event. This way, the dbl-clicks that were queued during the macro's execution are handled with no effect during these two seconds.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Static NextTime As Variant ' Will set a barrier for launching again the macro 
    If Not IsEmpty(NextTime) Then If Now < NextTime Then Exit Sub

    ListBox1.Enabled = False
    ' Any event code
    launch_macro
    ' ...
    ListBox1.Enabled = True

    NextTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2) ' dbl-click events will have no effects during next 2 seconds
End Sub
```

Comment: If you define `NextTime` as `Date` you won't need to check for `IsEmpty`, and it will be initialised as day 0 so `Now` won't be less than its initial value.

Comment: @YowE3K good spot. It's left to OP to change it, I personally prefer to leave it this way because I see it explicitly, but it's only a personal choice :)

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks. Using the Static variable approach might well do the trick but then using `Static NextTime As Single` and using `Timer` instead of `Now` should even let me use as little as a 0.1s delay, and it makes the `ListBox1.Enabled` statements useless. I'll test that tomorrow since it's now almost 2am here (ie `Const myNeededSleepTime As Single = 6*3600` and `nextTime = Timer + myNeededSleepTime`...)

Comment: @Tibo Dim Have As Good.Dreams :)

Comment: Your suggestion (combined with `nextTime As Single` and `Timer`) "does the trick" (with a reasonable delay) ; thanks. But I still don't like that ListBox1 is still enabled and Excel is still queueing events, thus I need to estimate how many time the user might Dbl_Click (depending on how long the macro takes) to estimate how much a delay I need (currently 0.5s to be able to handle (and log) at least 10 canceled events). Also, it seems like Excel doesn't really like (in regards to performance) queuing events while the macro is running.

Comment: Yeah this not elegant we have to admit. The double-click event seems not concerned with the disabling of the control... Disabling concerns the ability of the user to select or type things inside the controls. This is probably by design.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to lock the critical section of code for a set amount of time.
The example below locks the critical part of Test() function in Sheet2 of an Excel workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Private booIsRunning As Boolean
Private Sub Test()

    If Not booIsRunning Then
        booIsRunning = True
        Debug.Print "Hello."
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "Sheet2.UnlockTest"
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub UnlockTest()
    booIsRunning = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. That might do the trick, but I'm not really willing to use Application.OnTime and multiple subs for such a simple problem). As for tricks, I prefer A.S.H's answer (my current solution)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If this is a user form then a better way of doing it might be found [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm).

Comment: I just had a look. It is indeed a `userform` but I'm pretty sure it won't work since it is not a "changing property" raising a different event, but the very same event (`ListBox1_DblClick`) raised while it (`ListBox1_DblClick`) is already being executed. As I stated regarding the "variable" approach (call it macroLaunched or blockEvents) : "This doesn't work since the second execution is launched **after** the end of the first event (thus the variable is set back to `False`)."